# Why LCID is not unique?

Tags: c#, .net, cultureinfo, lcid

Why LCID is not unique? My code:

```
var data = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures)
  .OrderBy(n=>n.LCID).ToArray().GroupBy(s => s.LCID)
  .Where(n=>n.Count() > 1).SelectMany(m => m);
```

I see two LCID is not unique: 4 and 31748.

Therefore I can't use such code:

```
Dictionary<Int32, CultureInfo> valid_lcids =
 CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures).ToDictionary(
 c => c.LCID, c => c);
```

Comment: It's because (4) Chinese (Simplified) and Chinese (Simplified) Legacy listed in the `AllCultures` property. Same goes for (31748), Chinese (Traditional). But thats probably not what you wanted to know ;)

Comment: LCIDs have been deprecated for the past 10 years.  Basic reason why :)  The operating system now also uses the culture identifiers that .NET uses, like "en-US".  So stop using LCIDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using CultureTypes.SpecificCultures

Comment: CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures) does not return cultures with unique LCIDs